# Creating webpage on form submit?

Tags: php

How is it possible to allow a user to create a webpage containing some html, based on their entries in a form?  ie. I would want them to be able to input a name and when the button is clicked, a webpage called that name would be created.  I imagine that this must be possible in php, but what functions/code would I be using?

Thank you!

Comment: please can you give more detail? do you want a dinamic page or the page should be created phisically?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to be kind of mean — we can't code an entire site for you.  You're going to have to either hire a developer or learn some PHP.  By your question and comments, you don't seem to know any PHP at all (which is fine — but it's not who Stack Overflow is meant for).

Comment: hehe, don't worry, I'm not asking for a whole site to be coded for me.  It's just incredibly useful for a newby like me to get a pointer in the right direction from some helpful guys.  Sure, StackOverflow is not specifically for me, it's for more professional guys, but is that a big deal.  Everyone has got to start somewhere and SO have expressly said they want people coming here from Google.  TBH, I don't see a massive issue-of course I'm going to have to learn some php, but it's very helpful getting a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can pose big security risks in the first place, anyways, suppose form is submitted with html text, you can go about something like this:

```
$handle = fopen('file_name.html', 'r+');
// write to file
fwrite($handle, $_POST['fieldname']);
close($handle);
```

**Note:** You got to consider **XSS and other security issues** because you are allowing users to create pages. Bad guys can exploit it easily.

**Resoures:**

**[PHP File Handling Functions](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/site_map-file.php)**

**[XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)**

Finally, a must read PHP security guide:

http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/

**Idea:**
Just allow them minimal of customization and use a pre-made page where you could insert this user data. Ofcourse as said, you need to sanitize the user-submitted data and consider security issues.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would ask myself if this really what I need.

Why don't you just create a basic template page and pass the data as a parameter?

Something like:

```
user.php?name=joachim
```

If you still want to do that, you could use the PHP functions for opening, writing and closing files:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php

Here's a tutorial on how to create a file in php:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filecreate.php

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a page that acts as a template that populates based on the fields you mention, unless you actually need a physical file.

The template makes changes and security much easier.

UPDATE: Basically you can either have your form submit to a page that prints those POSTed fields to the appropriate spots or post to a database and then pull to the page.

Comment: Any chance you can expand on that slightly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to extract the entries of the form from the $_GET or $_POST arrays, and then use file writing functions such as fwrite to create a file. Theres an example on how to do a simple write [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php).

Answer (score 0):

*Excluding the fact that it is a security risk to allow users to create any files on the host...*

You can create a file via `fopen`(), `fwrite()` and `fclose()` or using `file_put_contents()`. I prefer using some kind of template file which you load first, then add the user input values in it and then save the whole string via `fwrite()` or `file_put_contents()`. You get the user inputs from the `$_GET` or `$_POST` array, depending on the method you used in your form.

Answer (score 0):

By saying "create a webpage containing some html, based on their entries in a form" I'm going to assume ( yeah yeah I know) that what you really mean is to determine the contents of a page by the entries from the form.

Gonna try and explain this as basically as possible, because I'm not completely sure I understand your intent.

When you write the form, you will have an  tag that contains action="example.php". This means that it will perform the actions on example.php

In example.php, you can then retrieve the variables passed to it from the form by looking within your [$_POST[] array variable](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp). Then, you can change the structure of example.php or your result page by using the variables in php to determine what you print.

I don't think generating a physical file would be necessary, and since you're using a form to get the information in, $_GET is kind of pointless (I'd guess in most cases).